# If I only have international health insurance will I be fined by not having Minimum Essential Coverage?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, health-insurance

I am an international student holding an F-1 visa, and I am working part time where I cannot apply for the employer health insurance. I only have international health insurance (bought in the US) and I was informed by the insurance provider that my insurance plan does not meet the Affordable Care Act's [Minimum Essential Coverage (MEC)](https://www.healthcare.gov/fees/plans-that-count-as-coverage/) requirements.

Do I need to pay a fine on my next tax return (2016)? Thank you very much.

---

Update: It is better to buy health insurance from the Marketplace for avoiding penalties if you have stayed in the US for more than 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not a US tax resident (and on F-1, you're probably not) then the ACA tax provision doesn't apply to you. You need to have the health insurance that is required by the visa conditions.

Comment: I am not a resident but I have stayed in the US for over 5 years. Does it affect my situation?

Comment: @DylanChen probaby.